Height above floor to drill service feed for electrical panel in freestanding garage
I will be running new service to a detached garage.
What is the minimum or recommended height above the slab to come out of the grand and drill the service wire for the panel?

Presumably this is underground, not overhead service? It can come up through the floor, (with more planning ahead than seems to have happened here, if the slab is in place when you ask the question) so there really isn't a minimum height. However, if your LAHJ requires expansion joints on conduit entering the ground, (which some don't - mine does) that does set a practical minimum (longer than the expansion joint at mid-adjustment) if it's coming up the outside of the wall.

If you're connecting off an existing electrical panel, that's a feeder not a service.  Services are only fed from utility-provided electric meters.   Note that you can't use the "whole dwelling service" table for your feeder size, you must use Table 310.16, though you can use the 75 degree C column if your wire/cable is not Romex/NM/UF.  Here, aluminum is very much your friend and 2 AWG is a popular choice.  Also note you don't NEED a 50-60A circuit to charge an EV. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Iyp_X3mwE1w
